# The set of all real $2\times2$ matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $V$ be the set of all $2\times2$ real matrices:
>   a) Show that $V$ is a $4$-dimensional vector space and find a basis.

I have the following:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0&1 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&1 \\ 
 0&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0 \\ 
 1&0 
\end{bmatrix}$$
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 &0  &0  &1 \\ 
 0&0  &0  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  &0 \\ 
 1&0  &0  &1 
\end{pmatrix}$$

> b) Let $C$ be a $2\times2$ matrix. Show that $L:V\rightarrow V$ given by $L(X)=CX$ and $R:V\rightarrow V$ given by $R(X)=XC$ are linear mappings

I figure I should show distributivity, but how?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by your fifth matrix. A base is simply made of the first four. For the question b), prove the defining properties of a linear mapping. Which are they?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For b, you want to show 
$$L(X+Y)=L(X)+L(Y),\quad L(aX)=aL(X) $$
i.e.,
$$ C(X+Y)=CX+CY,\quad aCX=CaX$$
i..e, that matrix multiplication distributes over matrix addition, and that scalar $aI$ cmmutes with all matrices.
But this is already a consequence of matrices representing linear maps:
For each $v\in\Bbb R^2$, $C(X+Y)v=C(Xv+Yv)=CXv+CYv$ and $aCXv=CXav=CaXv$.

If this feels too abstract, just perform the explicit matrix multiplications required ...